# Is there a word for a false accuser?

Tags: synonyms

Obviously other than false accuser. Something like charlatan but specifically when someone is making a false claim against another.

Comment: Some of the following might be relevant: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/slanderer/synonyms

Comment: @sumelic Ah, that's pretty much what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: is this someone accusing someone of doing something they didn't, or someone being hypocritical in their accusations?

Comment: The first example, but now I'm curious if there's a different name for both examples you've presented?